# Gradient on canvas.drawColor

Tags: java, android, eclipse, background

I have this code to draw one colour background, but I looking for gradient background.

```
canvas.drawColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
```

How can I change this code to draw linear gradient on background?

Thanks to all!

Comment: use Paint.setShader and then Canvas.draw* with that Paint object

Comment: THanks pskink...I learning programming, can you explain a little bit more how can I use cansvas.Draw in my code?